# php update password or save default if it is blank

Tags: php

Can someone point me out how can I save the default password if it is blank?
Its an update issue. Im making an update page when the user update their profile.
Its a long profile info. I did not post it all here coz my only problem is the password field.
Even if it is leave as blank it still updating the field on the database.I use md5 for encryption. Below is the code. Please just add the code, your code. Thank you.

The id is=1 because im just testing it. Ill only have one data in the userstest table.

```
    $desire= $_POST['desired'];//username field
    $password = md5(trim(mysql_prep($_POST['password'])));//password field
    $passconfirm = md5(trim(mysql_prep($_POST['confirmpassword']))); //confirmpasswor field
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE userstest SET username = '$desire',password='$password',confirmpassword='$passconfirm' WHERE id=1");
    if(mysql_affected_rows()==1){
    echo "Update Successfull";
    }else{
    echo "Update Failed" . mysql_error();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't update the `password` or `confirmpassword` columns if those fields are blank. Just don't add them to the SQL query in that case.

By the way, why are you even saving the `confirmpassword`? Shouldn't this always be the same as `password`? It's usually only used in an `if` statement in the PHP script to see that the user didn't do a typo.

Comment: alright.what if the user update the password field? i mean there should be an option for the user right? if the update the password field then it will be update. if not and it is blank then the default password will still be saved.

Comment: Your idea solveds my problem. I make an if else statement and use the empty keyword. if password is empty i did not include it on update.otherwise if its not empty it will be updated.but then i moved the md5 keyword inside MySql statement and that do the trick :). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add a if condition while building query

```
$sql = "UPDATE userstest SET username = '$desire'"; 
if($password) {$sql += ",password='$password',confirmpassword='$passconfirm'";}
$sql += " WHERE id=1";
```

then run the query mysql_query($sql);

Comment: i try your code. yes the password field does not update.but same as above comment. how about if the user update the password field?

Comment: in that case $password is not null, so it will append that to your query